# How do I override / extend a prototype.js class in a completely seperate .js file

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

I have a prototype.js class that I would like to extend to both add some new functions and override a couple of the functions already there.

in the example below I would like to add initAutocompleteNew and edit initAutocomplete to alert "new".

```
Varien.searchForm = Class.create();
Varien.searchForm.prototype = {
    initialize : function(form, field, emptyText){
        this.form   = $(form);
        this.field  = $(field);
        this.emptyText = emptyText;

        Event.observe(this.form,  'submit', this.submit.bind(this));
        Event.observe(this.field, 'focus', this.focus.bind(this));
        Event.observe(this.field, 'blur', this.blur.bind(this));
        this.blur();
    },
//////more was here

    initAutocomplete : function(url, destinationElement){
            alert("old");
    },
}
```

someone suggested but that doesn't work I think it's jQuery?

```
$.extend(obj_name.prototype, {
    newfoo : function() { alert('hi #3'); }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This article should help out: http://prototypejs.org/learn/class-inheritance

It looks like you're defining your classes the 'old' way as described in the first example on that page. Are you using 1.7?

Assuming you are using 1.7, if you wanted to override or add methods to your class, you can use [Class.addMethods](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/prototype/addMethods/):

```
Varien.searchForm.addMethods({
  initAutocomplete: function(url, destinationElement) {
    // Your new implementation
    // This will override what was previously defined
    alert('new');
  },
  someNewMethod: function() {
    // This will add a new method, `someNewMethod`
    alert('someNewMethod');
  }
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gqWDC/

Comment: Yeah I am using 1.7 that worked prefectly thanks dontGoPlastic.

Comment: Is there a way to call a parent method from the override?

Comment: @Tim Does $super not work (detailed in the class inheritance post)?

Comment: As far as I understand `$super` will only work with `Class.create` and not `addMethods`.

Comment: @Tim If you can confirm that through testing, then I guess you have your answer... Otherwise, I'd start a new question. I'm not sure without testing/digging myself.

Comment: If you want to override an existing method but be able to call the parent, do this :
`Varien.searchForm = Class.create(Varien.searchForm, { initAutocomplete: function ($super, url, destinationElement) { $super(url, destinationElement); // Do stuff } });`